# Typedef in class

Tags: c++

There is such code:

```
template <class T>
class SomeClass{
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<T> sPtr;
    typedef std::vector<sPtr> c;
    typedef c::iterator cIt;  // here is the problem
};
```

and the error is:

```
main.cpp:23: error: type ‘std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<X>, std::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<X> > >’ is not derived from type ‘SomeClass<T>’
main.cpp:23: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘cIt’
```

How to use typedef to templated parameters in class?

EDIT:

I figured it out, for g++ that must be:

```
typedef typename c::iterator cIt;  // here is the problem
```

Please close it.

Comment: The code you show is fine. You should provide a complete example that reproduces the error.

Comment: @Mścisław: If you found the solution yourself, you should answer your own question, and then accept that answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `c::iterator` is a *qualified-id*, and the type of `c` depends on a template paramater. According to `§14.6/3`:

> When a *qualified-id* is intended to refer to a type that is not a member of the current instantiation and its *nested-name-specifier* refers to a dependent type, it shall be
>   prefixed by the keyword typename ...